# Strange old smithing machine, what is it purpose?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, metallurgy, engineering-history

Is anyone familiar with such thing?
I suppose that is something used in forge. I don't have better photos, but "steering wheel" was placed on shaft with small gear and this small gear is powering the big gear. Small wheels on front view are for adjusting depth of something like vice handles or something like this, with screw handle.

[image: Back view]

[image: Front view]

Comment: Guess ; shapes steel tires for wooden wheels.

Comment: I think your picture is missing a piece that presses down on the work in the middle. Compare with a miniature version designed for curving guitar fret wire:  https://www.amazon.co.uk/Guyker-Guitar-Fretwire-Bender-Straightening/dp/B07ZYQQKJD (many luthiers still build their own versions of similar devices, rather than buying one.